# How to install 32-bit Windows apps on 64-bit Ubuntu (ver : 14.04)?

Tags: windows, wine, 64-bit, 32-bit, winetricks

I am getting errors while running 32-bit windows applications via Wine 1.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. Please help.

Comment: oh sorry...but i tried the methods given there...but none worked for me

Comment: Did you try the second post down (installing wine 1.4?) Wine is not perfect either, not an excuse as there is probably a solution for your specific program, but what program(s) are you having trouble with? They may be on the Wine forums too

Comment: Yep I did try the second option too, but it didn't work. Currently installed is Wine 1.7. From Photoshop to Ms Office, none is ready to work with the current configuration...Nitro Reader strictly gives the error message that I must download the 64-bit version of its program to run in the present configuration.

Comment: Ubuntu is not a drop in replacement for Windows and wine can be complicated . Best search winehq for your application - https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true . Often it is easier to either dual boot or run your applications in KVM or Virtualbox.

Comment: okay...thanks anyway...I'l try out your suggestions.